# Duplicating result due to loop

Tags: php

So my code get a value from previous page, compare it with a table field in the database and display success or failure. Here is the original code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['q'] !='')
{
    include('config.inc');
    $foo = $_GET['q'];
    $query= "INSERT INTO register(name) VALUES('$foo')";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_student");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id= $row['sid'];
        if($id==$foo)
        {
            $res = mysql_query($query);
            if ($res)
            {
                echo 'Insertion ok';
            }
            else
            {
                echo " ";
                echo "Attendance already taken for $foo";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo " ";
            echo "Student $foo does not exist!!";
        }
    }

}
else echo "Invalid Command";
?>
```

Am having duplicating result e.g **Student 1124 does not exist!!** 10times. I've modify the code to:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id= $row['sid'];
    if($id==$foo)
    {
        $res = mysql_query($query);
    }
    else
    {
        echo " ";
        echo "Student $foo does not exist!!";
    }
}
if ($res)
{
    echo 'Insertion ok';
}
else
{
    echo " ";
    echo "Attendance already taken for $foo";
}
```

So i've placed the $res outside the loop to avoid duplication result but now it says: **variable cannot be resolved** Any suggestions?

Comment: Dude, sort your code formatting out.

Comment: I've tried, but i can't get it right

Comment: fixed code formatting. @PeteR look now ;)

Comment: @poncha: Now I wish you hadn't. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like

```
<?php
if ($_GET['q'] !='')
{
    include('config.inc');
    $foo = $_GET['q'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_student");
    $bRecordExists = false;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id= $row['sid'];
        if($id==$foo)
        {
            $bRecordExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($bRecordExists)
    {
            $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO register(name) VALUES('$foo')");
            if ($res)
            {
                echo 'Insertion ok';
            }
            else
            {
                    echo " ";
                    echo "Attendance already taken for $foo";
            }
    }
    else
    {
        echo " ";
        echo "Student $foo does not exist!!";
    }

}
else
{
    echo "Invalid Command";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure, full scan of database table after fetching it into php is great stuff ;) Right?

Comment: @user3342746 i would recommend using answer by dikirill and not this one. It is more efficient (improves the code, not just fixes your original problem)

Comment: he just asked to fix the code.. sure it is not the most optimal way.. but maybe it is implemented that way for some reason.. it is not my place to guess...

Answer (score 2):

A bit of changed version of CaldasGSM:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['q']))
{
    include('config.inc');
    $foo = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_student WHERE sid = '{$foo}'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows > 0)
    {
        $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO register(name) VALUES('$foo')");
        if ($res)
        {
            echo 'Insertion ok';
        }
        else
        {
            echo " ";
            echo "Attendance already taken for $foo";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo " ";
        echo "Student $foo does not exist!!";
    }
}
else
{
 echo "Invalid Command";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just one note here... it's nice that you cast the input to int, but `q=AAA`, `q=0`, `q=FOO` (and many others) would collide into `0` which is not really good. I'd add check for `ctype_digit($_GET['q'])` to the  condition instead

Comment: thats why i added a comment instead of editing the answer / submitting my own ;)

Comment: Added escape and quotes.